# Datetime and numbers localization in adreportstats async query

Tags: facebook-ads-api

Is there any way to set datetime and numbers format based on locale info in adreportstats asynchronous queries? I've tried to fetch data with request parameter "locale" but it fails.

UPD:
There is no code for this issue. I just want to get in response localized json data. Here is response example:

```
{
'data': [
{ 
    'adgroup_id': 1,
    'country': 'US',
    'gender': 'female',
    'date_start': 2013-09-01,
    'date_stop': 2013-09-02,
    'reach': 2000,
    'ctr': 0.42333333333333 
},
{ 
    'adgroup_id': 2,
    'country': 'UK',
    'gender': 'male',
    'date_start': 2013-09-01,
    'date_stop': 2013-09-02,
    'reach': 1500,
    'ctr': 0.33333333333333 
},
...
]}
```

I want to get it for "de_DE" locale:

```
{
'data': [
{ 
    'adgroup_id': 1,
    'country': 'US',
    'gender': 'female',
    'date_start': 01.09.2013,   <------ de_DE localized date
    'date_stop': 02.09.2013,
    'reach': 2000,
    'ctr': 0,42333333333333     <------ de_DE localized number
},
{ 
    'adgroup_id': 2,
    'country': 'UK',
    'gender': 'male',
    'date_start': 01.09.2013,
    'date_stop': 02.09.2013,    
    'reach': 1500,
    'ctr': 0,33333333333333     
},
...
]}
```

Comment: Could you please include your code in the questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design: "The Ads API does not support the "locale" parameter. The supported parameters for Ad Report Stats are documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/"